# How to pass and call a function as an argument in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm looking to pass an anonymous function to another function, but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd like.

I've attached the code, I think it'd give you a better idea what I'd to do.

How do I successfully pass a function as an argument, and then invoke it?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function do_work(success) {
    success;
}

do_work(function () {
    alert("hello")
});

</script>
```

Comment: The `language` attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT).

Comment: wait!  does that mean no more vbscript?  ;))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to actually call the function:

```
function do_work(success) {
    success();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The variable *success* is an "instance" of [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function), so you can also call *apply()*, that will allow you to redefine the scope :

```
function do_work(success) {
    var foo = {
       bar : "bat"          
    }
    success.apply(foo);
}

do_work(function () {
 alert(this.bar)
});
```