# How to execute a javascript function passed as an argument to another function?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass and call a function as an argument in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868324/how-to-pass-and-call-a-function-as-an-argument-in-javascript)

Is the code bellow correct for executing a function passed as an argument to another function? Or should the line `callback;` be replaced with `callback();`, or something else?

```
function load(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var s = arg1 + arg2;
    callback;
}
```

Also, would there need to be a different approach for passing anonymous functions as arguments? i.e.:

```
load(1, 2, function(){ 
    // do something 
});
```

Comment: Did you try executing using the `callback()` syntax you noted in the question?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work.

Comment: If it didn't work, then why did you accept an answer that does exactly that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this way:

```
function load(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var s = arg1 + arg2;
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the callback argument like a normal function. So try: `callback()`

The way you pass in your nameless function is perfectly valid. But if you are interested, you don't always have to use a nameless function. You can also do:

```
function aCallbackFunction() 
{
 //doSomething    
}
load(1, 2, aCallbackFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is

```
callback.apply(this, args);
```

[`apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)