# In JS, how do you pass a function back to another function to be evaluated

Tags: javascript

I'm not even sure how to ask this question.

In Javascript, I want to call a function to determine what units to include in a measurement, but, if the measurement is a certain unit, I want to pass back a calculation to the calling function for it to evaluate.

Simplistically, I am calling the function "Unit" using a measurement name

```
unit(details)
```

where details is, for example, 'calories'.

The unit function is simply:

```
    function unit(measure) {
        if ( measure == "cadence" ) { return " rpm "; };
        if ( measure == "calories" ) { return " calories " + " ( " + Math.round( 4.184 * function(){event[key][details]} ) + " kJ )"; };
        ...
        ...
    }
```

If 'measure' is calories, I want to pass back a formula for the calling function to evaluate based on its variables.

Is this possible?

Apologies if this is a simple question and i'm just missing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass and call a function as an argument in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868324/how-to-pass-and-call-a-function-as-an-argument-in-javascript)

Comment: You're wrong, @Cerbrus, because this is not about passing a function as an argument, but returning a function from another function.

Comment: Ah, yeap. That's right.

Answer (score 4):

An anonymous function must be declared directly after the return keyword.

```
function unit(measure) {
    if ( measure == "cadence" ) { return " rpm "; };
    if ( measure == "calories" ) { return function(){
        //calculation goes here
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will that work for you?

```
function unit(measure) {
    var measurements = {
        cadence: {
            value: "rpm"
            formula: null
        },
        calories: {
            value: "calories",
            formula: function() {
                return Calories(....);
            }
        }
    };
    return measurements[measure];
};
```

This way, you can remove multiple if-else branching.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I like this approach but i'm still just getting the returned function as text rather than it evaluating.

Comment: calories : 166 calories function () { return "Calories (" + Math.round(4.184 * event[key][details]) + "kJ)";}

Comment: @colster: Have you defined the Calories function somewhere else. If yes, then you can simply call the function without using string, like this: return Calories(Math.round(4.184 * event[key][details]) + "KJ");

Comment: 'calories' isn't a function, it's just the first part of the text string "Calories (" +.....

Comment: i can get the function back and assign it to a variable.  e.g. temp = function(){ return "Calories... etc, and temp is recognised as a Function type, but i can't get it to evaluate.

Comment: I know i'm missing something stupid.  Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ueF54/

Comment: @colster: Glad you got it. In future, if you encounter multiple if-else branching, you can try using the object notation.

Answer (score 0):

As functions are first class constructs in JS you can return functions as normal variables.

```
if(measure === "calories") {
    return function(key, details) {
        return "Calories (" + Math.round(4.184 * event[key][details] + "kJ)"
    }
}
```